# Missing package github.com/docker/docker/autogen/dockerversion

Tags: docker

Trying to compile Docker in Windows according to the instructions here:

[How to compile Docker on Windows](https://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/compiling-docker-cli-on-windows/)

and getting this error message:

`cannot find package "github.com/docker/docker/autogen/dockerversion" in any of:`

Tried browsing to https://github.com/docker/docker/autogen/dockerversion but getting a 404; can anyone tell me how to get this using GIT client?

Comment: That link is only valid up to https://github.com/docker/docker There is no such folder labeled autogen no matter what client you use.

Comment: Just reading here that I have to do something in GitBash so trying to figure it out: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10922

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the author has updated the post as you have seen to include the use of GitBash. You will need to update your source to get the new 'hack' directory content used in the instructions he outlines as per below:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/docker/docker.git  /c/gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker
cd /c/gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker
export GOPATH=/c/gopath:/c/gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor
export DOCKER_CLIENTONLY=1
chmod +x hack/make/.go-autogen && hack/make/.go-autogen
cd docker
go build
```

Do you have GitBash installed? All of the instructions he provides need to be run in a GitBash window not the Windows Command window now.

I have built it successfully, so if you need any more help I may be of use.